# cocoa method strange availability

Tags: cocoa, methods, availability

For example:

class NSNotificationCenter

method deaultCenter

xcode 8.0

OS 10.12

availability **macOS (10.12 and later)**

**BUT**

xcode 5.1.1

OS 10.8

availability **OS X v10.0 and later**

Why? Can I use "deaultCenter" in OS 10.8? And how can I know that some methods have the  real "macOS (10.12 and later)" (crash in early OS version) availability?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current online copy of the [`defaultCenter` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotificationcenter/1414169-defaultcenter?language=objc) correctly says 10.0+. If Xcode 8 is not agreeing then it's a documentation bug. You can file a report at bugreport.apple.com

Comment: And [NSColor  clearColor]?[clearColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1527217-clearcolor)

Comment: And [blackColor](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscolor/1527194-blackcolor?language=objc)... File a bug report, looks like Apple has made a mess.